# Is there a infix function equivalent for `flip (.)` has same or nearby infix level with `(.)`?

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

Is there a infix function equivalent for `flip (.)` has same or nearby infix level with `(.)` ?

(not self defined, just like  `flip ($)` for `(&)` in module `Data.Function`)

In `Control.Category`, `(<<<)` and `(>>>)` is `infixr 1`, and `(.)` is `infixr 9`,  the infix level between them are too far away.

Comment: [This](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+c) may interest you. Right off the bat, `(|>)` from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hx-0.4/docs/Haskell-X-Ops.html#v:-124--62-) might be what you want.

Comment: @Alec Thank you very much